# Excel formula: Sum if two columns match

Tags: excel, if-statement, sum, excel-formula, sumifs

I need a formula that only sums numbers in a cell from a column if it matches two cells in the same row.

In J3 i'm trying to get the sum of all the returns that are from January 2009.
In J4 'm trying to get the sum of all the returns that are from february 2009.
And so on.

[image: The datasheet]

I tried different sumifs but it didn't return the value.

Comment: what is your data column format? mm-dd-yyyy or dd-mm-yyyy?

Comment: and what is the format of the entries in column **I**?

Comment: Nothing in I, that was just a column for myself to make it easy to what month it was for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your formula for J3 look like this?

SUMIFS(B$3:B$22, D$3:D$22, G3, E$3:E$22, H3)

Answer (score 0):

Without the *helper* columns and I3 as *01/01/2009* (i.e. the first day of the month to be examined) then either of these,

```
=sumifs(b$3:b$22, c$3:c$22, ">="&i3, c$3:c$22, "<"&edate(i3, 1))
=sumifs(b$3:b$22, c$3:c$22, ">="&date(2009, 1, 1), c$3:c$22, "<"&date(2009, 2, 1))
```